# I need to migrate Kotlin Corotine experimental functions to stable version

Tags: android, kotlin, mvvm, kotlin-coroutines

I want to migrate an existing Android app to recent coroutine release. Anybody out there to help rewriting this Kotline-coroutine funtions. I need these functions launchAsync async and asyncAwait functions exactly as it describe here in my viewmodel.

```
package com.xx.xxx.xxxx.

import kotlinx.coroutines.experimental.CommonPool
import kotlinx.coroutines.experimental.CoroutineScope
import kotlinx.coroutines.experimental.Deferred
import kotlinx.coroutines.experimental.Job
import kotlinx.coroutines.experimental.android.UI
import kotlinx.coroutines.experimental.async
import kotlinx.coroutines.experimental.launch

fun launchAsync(block: suspend CoroutineScope.() -> Unit): Job {
    return launch(UI) { block() }
}

suspend fun <T> async(block: suspend CoroutineScope.() -> T): Deferred<T> {
    return async(CommonPool) { block() }
}

suspend fun <T> asyncAwait(block: suspend CoroutineScope.() -> T): T {
    return async(block).await()
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

These are the literal translations:

`launch(UI) { block() }` -> `GlobalScope.launch(Main, block = block)`

`async(CommonPool) { block() }` -> `GlobalScope.async(block = block)`. Also, your function is marked as `suspend` for no reason.

`async(block).await()` -> `withContext(Default, block = block)`

However, the stable coroutines have introduced a very important additional feature: structured concurrency. You should not use `GlobalScope` as shown, but define proper scopes and use them.

Comment: I am getting errors in IDE. i need to use this launchAsync, async, asyncAwait somewhere. And them are suspend functions.

Comment: You asked for literal translations that don't even touch the function signature declarations. If you didn't have errors in the project with experimental coroutines, you won't have errors after the switch.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code I use now. With the help of @Marko,sharing for others to use.

```
fun launchAsync(block: suspend CoroutineScope.() -> Unit): Job {
    return GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.Main) { block() }
}

suspend fun <T> async(block: suspend CoroutineScope.() -> T): Deferred<T> {
    return GlobalScope.async(Dispatchers.Default) { block() }
}

suspend fun <T> asyncAwait(block: suspend CoroutineScope.() -> T): T {
    return async(block).await()
}
```

Any additions? Marko?